# jqmodal event when modal goes away

Tags: jqmodal

when you click outside the modal to close it can you hook into any events to run more code?

thanks,
rodchar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare a callback.

```
var myClose=function(hash) { /* YOUR STUFF */ };

$('#dialog').jqm({onHide:myClose});
```